# how to change Excel column width

Tags: vb.net, winforms, excel, visual-studio

I'm handling an excel file using visual studio 2013, visual basic, windows Forms.

- I add new sheet to excel named sheetReport

How to change the column `width` of b to be 30?

I don't need to use `autofit`, cause it make text small to fit in cell with it's default width.

```
xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False
xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
SheetReport = CType(xlBook.Sheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
SheetReport.Name = "Report"
SheetReport.Range("B2").Value = "Agent Name"
' need resize column b
```

Comment: `SheetReport.Range("B2").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 30`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply:

```
SheetReport.Range("B2").ColumnWidth = 30
```

To learn the code with Excel API I'll give you a trick you can use; just open a Excel Sheet, start recording a Macro, and then do the thing you want to do programatically. Then stop the recording and look for the code recorded of the macro.

It will contain the instructions in VBA to make it possible. With a little modification, that's what you need to do in VB.NET with the Excel API.